# Merging files with the same header in different directories

Tags: bash, find, sh

I have this folder structure with 300+ folders all of different names but all with the same csv filename:

```
some folder name > file_name.csv
some other folder name > file_name.csv
...
another folder name > file_name.csv
```

All the files have a header row and I'm trying to merge all files into a single file with only one header.

Had a look around questions with a similar problem and have gotten to this point, but this doesn't work and will still output the header multiple times in the final output file. When I have all files in the same directory with different names then `awk 'NR == 1 || FNR > 1' *.csv >> $OUTPUT_LOCATION \;` works. Can someone explain why this doesn't work when my files are in different directories and suggest an alternative?

```
rm -f $OUTPUT_LOCATION

find . -name 'file_name.csv' \
  -exec awk 'NR == 1 || FNR > 1' {} >> $OUTPUT_LOCATION \;
```

Comment: So all files are in the same format? Can you post an example of the format?

Comment: Yes all the same format, with the same headers. Standard CSV files.

Comment: @oguzismail that works! (on the test dataset) Can you explain why? And when would be too many files? I have 340 folders to iterate through and about 31GB of data to merge in total.

Comment: If you punctuate `-exec` with a semicolon, the program will be executed once for each selected file. But with a plus sign the program is run once for every couple thousands of files. The number may vary, but is always finite

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At present you are executing the awk command for each file found by the find command. To preserve the NR and FNR logic in the existing command. Redirect the find results back into awk to process multiple files and so:

```
awk 'NR == 1 || FNR > 1' $(find . -name 'file_name.csv') >> $OUTPUT_LOCATION
```

Answer (score 1):

Changing `\;` to `+` will help if there aren't too many `file_name.csv`s. But here is a fail-safe approach just in case:

```
rm output.csv
find . -name 'file_name.csv' -exec sh -c '
if ! test -f output.csv; then
  cp "$1" output.csv
  shift
fi
tail -q -n +2 "$@" >>output.csv' sh {} +
```

Export `OUTPUT_LOCATION` and use it in place of `output.csv` if necessary.

Answer (score 1):

`csvstack` from the handy [csvkit](https://csvkit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) bundle of utilties is made for this:

```
csvstack **/file_name.csv > joined.csv
```